# AngularJS - get properties of selected option in dropdown

Tags: angularjs, html-select

Starting out on Angular and using select dropdowns are really confusing me. Basically I am getting JSON object using an AJAX call and then populating my form with JSON using AngularJS.

For the dropdown, the settings.metric = '2' from database. So the selected is "cm".

My question is, how do I get the currently selected option and its datavalue? I tried scope.settings.metric but all that gives me is "2". I like to get the other properties of the selected such as **name** and **datavalue**.

```
$scope.metrics = [
            {id:1,name:'in',value:'1',datavalue:'in'},
            {id:2,name:'cm',value:'2',datavalue:'cm'},
            {id:3,name:'px',value:'3',datavalue:'px'},
            {id:4,name:'pt',value:'4',datavalue:'pt'}
            ];

<select 
    ng-model="settings.metric" // this is 2 from database call
    ng-options="p.value as p.name for p in metrics" >
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty simple with what you already have. You have to write this.

```
ng-options="p as p.name for p in metrics"
```

The first parameter 'p' is the value that will be stored.
The second parameter 'p.name' is the value displayed in the option.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. But I was wondering how to access the currently selected option properties from outside in another javascript function... any ideas?

Comment: check the value of the `ng-model`

Comment: @ScottYu-UXdesigner If you do it this way you have the whole object in scope.settings.metric

Comment: @ZackArgyle Thats weird.. I tried doing scope.settings.metric but all I get is "2"...  I finally had to do scope.metrics[parseFloat(scope.settings.metric-1)].datavalue;

Comment: @ScottYu-UXdesigner, Don't know how you are doing it, but here is a fiddle that seems to be working fine with your stuff. [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/JCD4F/1/)

Comment: Yes your fiddle works perfectly.. I just need to figure out what I am doing wrong then.

Comment: Okay, I had to add $scope.settings.metric = $scope.metrics[$scope.settings.metric-1]; to make it so when it first shows up, the dropdown picks default selection based on database retrieved value...